# Can not send text message from android app using smooch-java

Tags: java, android, smooch

I tried to send a text message from Android app using `smooch-java` but got bad request everytime.

My code:

```
        String jwt = "";
        try {
            jwt = Jwts.builder()
                    .claim("scope", "app")
                    .setHeaderParam(KEY_ID, "MY_KEY_ID")
                    .signWith(
                            SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,
                            "MY_SECRET".getBytes("UTF-8")
                    )
                    .compact();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!jwt.isEmpty()) {
            ApiClient defaultClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();

            ApiKeyAuth apiKeyAuth = (ApiKeyAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("jwt");
            apiKeyAuth.setApiKey(jwt);
            apiKeyAuth.setApiKeyPrefix("Bearer");

            ConversationApi apiInstance = new ConversationApi();
            String userId = preferencesRepository.getUserId();
            MessagePost messagePostBody = new MessagePost();
            messagePostBody.setRole("appUser");
            messagePostBody.setType(MessagePost.TypeEnum.TEXT);
            messagePostBody.setText(message);
            try {
                PostMessagesResponse result = apiInstance.postMessage(userId, messagePostBody);
                Log.d(TAG, "sendMessage: " + result);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "sendMessage:", e);
            }
        }
```

Error logs:

`io.smooch.client.ApiException: Bad Request`

`{"error":{"code":"bad_request","description":".items: should not have less than 1 items"}}`

From [Docs](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#post-message), This is a text message and I don't need any `items` but the error said that I need at least one `item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the lib to 1.2.0 but still got error. But I fixed it by setting items to null:

```
    String jwt = "";
    try {
        jwt = Jwts.builder()
                .claim("scope", "app")
                .setHeaderParam(KEY_ID, "MY_KEY_ID")
                .signWith(
                        SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,
                        "MY_SECRET".getBytes("UTF-8")
                )
                .compact();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!jwt.isEmpty()) {
        ApiClient defaultClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();

        ApiKeyAuth apiKeyAuth = (ApiKeyAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("jwt");
        apiKeyAuth.setApiKey(jwt);
        apiKeyAuth.setApiKeyPrefix("Bearer");

        ConversationApi apiInstance = new ConversationApi();
        String userId = preferencesRepository.getUserId();
        MessagePost messagePostBody = new MessagePost();
        messagePostBody.setRole("appUser");
        messagePostBody.setType(MessagePost.TypeEnum.TEXT);
        messagePostBody.setText(message);
        messagePostBody.setItems(null);
        try {
            PostMessagesResponse result = apiInstance.postMessage(userId, messagePostBody);
            Log.d(TAG, "sendMessage: " + result);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "sendMessage:", e);
        }
    }
```

And it worked

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was a bug in the generated wrapper related to [this issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/5363).

The Smooch codegen fork has been updated and a new version of the wrapper has been [released](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-java/releases/tag/1.2.0). This version should work correctly.